# R merge data frames matching row- _and_ colnames

Tags: r, join, insert, merge

I'm looking for an easy way to combine two data frames by inserting the smaller one into the bigger one, like that:

```
 x.1:                              x.2:
         1.1  1.2  2.3  3.4                 1.2  2.3
    a.b    w              z            d.e    u
    b.c         x                      a.b         v
    d.e    y
```

The desired result:

```
 x.f:
         1.1  1.2  2.3  3.4
    a.b    w         v    z
    b.c         x
    d.e    y    u
```

So many questions went for merging after cols only, but I want to merge according to the names of cols *and* rows and don't get it. The points in the names are a fix scheme. Would be glad if someone comes up with an advice, since my tries with merge, join, etc. didn't succeed. One solution in my mind is the manual way by looping through the smaller frame, looking for values and saving row/col each time, then insert in the bigger frame. Or restructuring my dataframes. But there must be an easier way?

Thx in advance,
Robin

Here's the code to quickly try out:

```
i<-c("w", "", "y")
j<-c("", "x", "")
k<-c("","","")
l<-c("z","","")
x.1 <- data.frame(i,j,k,l, row.names=c("a.b","b.c","d.e"))
colnames(x.1)<-c("1.1","1.2","2.3","3.4")
m<-c("u", "")
n<-c("", "v")
x.2 <- data.frame(m,n, row.names=c("d.e","a.b"))
colnames(x.2)<-c("1.2","2.3")
```

Comment: What if there is a value for a certain row/column combination for *both* `data.frame`s, or is that an impossible scenario?

Comment: Do you mean, how to handle the case when a value is going to be inserted in a spot already holding a value? Well that should be no scenario, but it could be due to errors while entering the data. I'll have to take care and look what happens with your solution. Btw it's working, many thx for this and your alternative!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
library(reshape2)
mx1 <- melt(cbind(id = rownames(x.1), x.1), id.vars="id")
mx2 <- melt(cbind(id = rownames(x.2), x.2), id.vars="id")
x12 <- rbind(mx1, mx2)
out <- dcast(x12[!x12$value == "", ], id ~ variable)
out[is.na(out)] <- ""
out
#    id 1.1 1.2 2.3 3.4
# 1 a.b   w       v   z
# 2 b.c       x        
# 3 d.e   y   u
```

Start by making each dataset into a "long" dataset (easiest using `melt` from "reshape2"), and then convert it back into a "wide" dataset (using `dcast`, again from "reshape2").

The above steps aren't *all* necessary, but I've included them to get as close as possible to your desired output so you can decide which steps to keep/drop.

---

Actually, if you asked me, I would stop at the "x12" stage. The "long" data would probably be much more convenient to manipulate and work with in the long run (no pun intended).

---

### Update

You may also want to consider the "datamerge" package, which really comprises two functions: `clean.factors()` and `version.merge`. The `clean.factors` function will take care of converting blanks to `NA` prior to merging. I've kept `verbose = TRUE` so you can see that it does give you some informative details about how the merge was carried out, including whether any values had to be changed in the process.

```
out <- Reduce(function(x, y) version.merge(x, y, add.values = TRUE, verbose = TRUE), 
              lapply(list(x.1, x.2), clean.factors, verbose = FALSE))
# Rows:  3 from `x` #1
#        0 from `y` #2
# 
# Columns:
# 1.1  Origin: `x` #1
# 1.2  Origin: `x` #1
#      Imputed 1 values from `y` #2
# 2.3  Origin: `x` #1
#      Imputed 1 values from `y` #2
#      Class missmatch: numeric vs. character
#      Converted to character
# 3.4  Origin: `x` #1

out
#      1.1  1.2  2.3  3.4
# a.b    w <NA>    v    z
# b.c <NA>    x <NA> <NA>
# d.e    y    u <NA> <NA>
```

Of course, if you wanted to replace the `NA`s with blanks again, you would just use `out[is.na(out)] <- ""`.

Comment: +1 I'd love to see the `data.table` syntax for this. I am expecting something fancy and whizy like `x.1[ mergemagic( x.2 ) ]` :-)

Comment: @SimonO101, well, now that Arun has basically been working on a melt and cast for data.table, there's a good chance that the syntax won't be too much different.

Answer (score 1):

```
flatx.2 <- which(!x.2 =="", arr.ind=TRUE)
flatx.2[] <- cbind( rownames(x.2)[flatx.2[,'row']], 
                    colnames(x.2)[flatx.2[,'col']])
flatx.2  
# contains row and column names in same positions as the non-blank x.2 values
#---------
    row   col  
d.e "d.e" "1.2"
a.b "a.b" "2.3"
#--------------
x.1[ cbind(  match(flatx.2[,1], rownames(x.1)),          #identify numeric row
            match(flatx.2[,2], colnames(x.1))) ] <-      #identify numeric col
                 x.2[which(!x.2 =="", arr.ind=TRUE)]    # the non-blank values
 x.1
#-------------
    1.1 1.2 2.3 3.4
a.b   w       v   z
b.c       x        
d.e   y   u
```

I happen to think this is pretty kewl using just base indexing maneuvers (and should be fairly efficient and applicable to data.table structures to those who have the needed skills), so hoping for a little applause. I thought I could just use the character valued matrix of positons on the LHS but got an error in my attempts. The `?"["` page sems to be saying that it should have worked so maybe this can be simplified if I made a syntactic error.

Comment: I also think this is pretty cool. Especially since I first had difficulties and errors by installing reshape2 ... but it finally worked by installing through compiling the package source. Will try out your code, too, many thx so far!